# Lost fragments in my shader

Tags: three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to do a tilesystem in Threejs: Green for ground / Blue for water.

I'm using a shader on a PlaneBufferGeometry.

Here is what I have so far :

> Relevant code :
>
> - JS: variable `chunk` and function `DoPlaneStuff()` (both at the beginning)
> - HTML: vertex and fragment shader

```js
var chunk = {
  // number of width and height segments for PlaneBuffer
  segments: 32,
  // Heightmap: 0 = water, 1 = ground
  heightmap: [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1],
  ],
  // size of the plane
  size: 40
};

function DoPlaneStuff() {
  var uniforms = {
    heightmap: {
      type: "iv1",
      // transform the 2d Array to a simple array
      value: chunk.heightmap.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c), [])
    },
    hmsize: {
      type: "f",
      value: chunk.heightmap[0].length
    },
    coord: {
      type: "v2",
      value: new THREE.Vector2(-chunk.size / 2, -chunk.size / 2)
    },
    size: {
      type: "f",
      value: chunk.size
    }
  };
  console.info("UNIFORMS GIVEN :", uniforms);
  var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("v_shader").textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("f_shader").textContent
  });
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(chunk.size, chunk.size, chunk.segments, chunk.segments),
    shaderMaterial
  );
  plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
  scene.add(plane);
}


// --------------------- END OF RELEVANT CODE


window.addEventListener("load", Init);

function Init() {
  Init3dSpace();
  DoPlaneStuff();
  Render();
}

var camera_config = {
  dist: 50,
  angle: (5 / 8) * (Math.PI / 2)
}
var scene, renderer, camera;
function Init3dSpace() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    logarithmicDepthBuffer: true
  });
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    50,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
  );
  this.camera.position.y = camera_config.dist * Math.sin(camera_config.angle);
  this.camera.position.x = 0;
  this.camera.position.z = 0 + camera_config.dist * Math.cos(camera_config.angle);
  this.camera.rotation.x = -camera_config.angle;
  var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 10);
  light.position.set(0, 50, 0);
  scene.add(light);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function Render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.min.js"></script>
<!-- VERTEX SHADER -->
<script id="v_shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  // size of the plane 
  uniform float size; 
  // coordinates of the geometry 
  uniform vec2 coord; 
  // heightmap size (=width and height of the heightmap)
  uniform float hmsize; 
  uniform int heightmap[9]; 
  varying float colorValue; 
  
  void main() { 
    int xIndex = int(floor( 
      (position.x - coord.x) / (size / hmsize)
    ));
    int yIndex = int(floor(
      (-1.0 * position.y - coord.y) / (size / hmsize)
    ));
    // Get the index of the corresponding tile in the array
    int index = xIndex + int(hmsize) * yIndex;
    // get the value of the tile
    colorValue = float(heightmap[index]);
  
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  }
</script>
<!-- FRAGMENT SHADER -->
<script id="f_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  varying float colorValue; 
  
  void main() {
    // default color is something is not expected: RED
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    // IF WATER
    if (colorValue == 0.0) { 
      // BLUE
      gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    }
    // IF GROUND
    if (colorValue == 1.0) {
      // GREEN 
      gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.1, 0.6, 0.0, 1.0 );
    }
  }
</script>
```

As you can see it's almost working, but I have these red lines splitting green and blue areas and I can't figure out why.
I call these red fragments the "lost one" because they don't map to any tile, and I can't get why.

I could only notice that with a greater value of `chunk.segments` (which is the number of height and width segments for the geometry) I can have thiner red lines.

I would like to know how to have a gradient fill between green and blue zones instead of red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red lines are formed by triangles that have some vertices lying in a ground tile and other vertices in a water tile. The GPU then interpolates the `colorValue` along the triangle, producing a smooth gradient with values from 0 to 1, instead of a sharp step that you probably expect.

There are several solutions for this. You can change the condition in your shader to choose the color based on the mid point: if `colorValue` < 0.5, output blue, otherwise green. That won't work well if you decide you want more tile types later on, though. A better solution would be to generate your geometry in a way that all vertices of all triangles lie in a single tile. That will involve doubling up vertices that lie on the tile boundaries. You can also add the `flat` interpolation qualifier to `colorValue`, but it's harder to control which vertices' attribute the triangle will end up using.

... I just noticed that you do want a gradient instead of a sharp step. That's even easier. You need to move the color selection code from the fragment shader to the vertex shader and just return the resulting interpolated color in the fragment shader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "The GPU then interpolates the colorValue along the triangle" That's why I couldn't have a varying int ! However, I'm not sure to understand what you mean in your "better solution", do you have some resources so I can have a look ?